# Is MSVC right to find this method call ambiguous, whilst Clang/GCC don't?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, clang, language-lawyer

Clang (3.9.1) and GCC (7, snapshot) print "1", "2" to the console when this code is run.

However, MSVC fails to compile this code:

> source_file.cpp(15): error C2668: 'Dictionary::set': ambiguous call to overloaded function
>
> source_file.cpp(9): note: could be 'void Dictionary::set(int64_t)'
>
> source_file.cpp(8): note: or       'void Dictionary::set(const char *)'
>
> source_file.cpp(15): note: while trying to match the argument list '(const unsigned int)'

```
#include <iostream>

static const unsigned ProtocolMajorVersion = 1;
static const unsigned ProtocolMinorVersion = 0;

class Dictionary {
public:
    void set(const char *Str) { std::cout << "1"; }
    void set(int64_t val) { std::cout << "2"; }
};

int main() {
    Dictionary dict;
    dict.set(ProtocolMajorVersion);
    dict.set(ProtocolMinorVersion);
}
```

I think MSVC is right - the value of `ProtocolMajorVersion` is `0`, which can be `NULL` or `int64_t(0)`.

However, this seems to be the case when replacing

```
dict.set(ProtocolMinorVersion)
```

with

```
dict.set(0);
```

> source_file.cpp:15:10: error: call to member function 'set' is ambiguous
>       dict.set(0);
>
> source_file.cpp:8:10: note: candidate function
>
> ```
> void set(const char *Str) { std::cout << "1"; }
> ```
>
> source_file.cpp:9:10: note: candidate function
>
> ```
> void set(int64_t val) { std::cout << "2"; }
> ```

So what's going on here - which compiler is right? Would surprise me if both GCC and Clang are accepting incorrect code, or is MSVC just being buggy? Please refer to the standard

Comment: It is ambiguous because the types don't match so it could be either. The size of 'unsigned' isn't necessarily 64-bit, so it's unlikely it matches in64_t type. Personally I'd prefer MSVCs way here - it's always good to be aware of ambiguity in C/C++ programs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++11 and before, any *integral constant expression* which evaluates to 0 is a considered a *null pointer constant*. This has been restricted in C++14: only integer literals with value 0 are considered. In addition, prvalues of type `std::nullptr_t` are null pointer constants since C++11. See [conv.ptr] and [CWG 903](http://wg21.link/cwg903).

Regarding overload resolution, both the integral conversion `unsigned` -> `int64_t` and the pointer conversion *null pointer constant* -> `const char*` have the same rank: Conversion. See [over.ics.scs] / Table 12.

So if `ProtocolMinorVersion` is considered a null pointer constant, then the calls are ambiguous. If you just compile the following program:

```
static const unsigned ProtocolMinorVersion = 0;

int main() {
    const char* p = ProtocolMinorVersion;
}
```

You will see that clang and gcc reject this conversion, whereas MSVC accepts it.

Since CWG 903 is considered a defect, I'd argue that clang and gcc are right.

Comment: As amusing as it might be, I think given `struct S { int x; }`, having `S().x` be a null pointer constant is a little too much :) This part of C++11 is nonsensical without CWG 903.

Answer (score 1):

When two compilers agree and one doesn't, it's nearly always the one that doesn't that is wrong.

I would argue that if you declare a value as `const unsigned somename = 0;`, it is no longer a simple zero, it is a named unsigned constant with the value zero. So should not be considered equivalent to a pointer type, leaving only one plausible candidate.

Having said that, BOTH of the `set` functions require conversion (it's not a `uint64_t`, neither a `const char *`), so one could argue that MSVC is right [the compiler shall pick the type that requires least conversion, if multiple types require equal amount of conversion, it's ambiguous] - although I still don't think the compiler should accept a named constant of the value zero as an equivalent to a pointer...

Sorry, probably more of a "comment" than an answer - I started writing with the intention of saying "gcc/clang are right", but then thinking more about it came to the conclusion that "although I would be happier with that behaviour, it's not clear that this is the CORRECT behaviour".

Comment: Integral conversions (like `int` -> `long long`) and pointer conversions (like `0` -> `char*`) have the same rank: Conversion. In C++11, any constant integer expression which is a *null pointer constant* can be used to initialize a pointer; this has been restricted in C++14, see http://wg21.link/cwg903

Comment: @dyp feel like turning that comment into an answer?

Comment: Disagree with first paragraph , it's a pretty weak heuristic IMO